# Custom vision upload multiple images in the same time

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services

Trying to upload multiple TRAINING images with custom vision SDK

```
for i in range(0,len(split_input)):
        img_byte=connection_blob(confidential)   #first I download images from my blob with a custom function, images names are in list split_input

        image_list.append(ImageFileCreateEntry(name=split_input[i], contents=img_byte, tag_ids=[hemlock_tag]))   #Then I create the list of images


for i in range(0,len(image_list)):
        upload_result = trainer.create_images_from_files(model_id, images=[image_list[i]],raw=True) #I push data on custom vision
```

My problem is sometimes it goes wrong and only some images are send. For exemple I'm trying to send 20 pictures and only 10 are sended...

Any idea of where to look to try to fix the problem?

Edit: Even when I try to send images 1 by 1, they are not uploaded

Comment: Did you check your images (max size, extension)? Do you check that you have any error during the call?

Comment: Yes images are clean (lower than 4MO, good extension). There was no error during the call that why I think it was caused by the fast images where similar

Comment: In that case, the API should return an information, no? The latest API doc says "If all images are successful created, 200(OK) status code will be returned. Otherwise, 207 (Multi-Status) status code will be returned and detail status for each image will be listed in the response payload."

Comment: Yes I just found the result part. API return "Okduplicated" in status. Thanks for help

Comment: Ok! In that case, if you can just edit your response to add more details, that would be helpful for other people facing the same case, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found the solution. Image are taken from a powerApps, and to make my test I was taking picture very fast. Some picture where strictly identical = custom vision only  accept one version of the images.

You can check upload status with:

```
for i in range(0,len(image_list)):
        upload_result = trainer.create_images_from_files(model_id, images=[image_list[i]],raw=True)
        res_upload_img=upload_result.output.images
        id_list.append(res_upload_img[0].image.id)  #Get ID of uploaded image so u can track them on custom vision
        img_status.append(res_upload_img[0].status)  #return status i.e for example "Ok" or "OkDuplicated" if images was already existing
```

Comment: I made a quick test through Custom Vision interface: yes, it looks like it is doing deduplication when you try to upload 2 times the same image